# How to access the data from a jquery post in php?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm using the following in my javascript:
`jQuery.post( "cmssave.php" , html_to_send , done_edit() , "html" )`

And on the PHP end I'm trying to get the posted data using:
`$data = $_POST['somevar']`

The problem is (I assume) I can't find what post variable is being used.
 When I do `var_dump($_POST)`
I get exactly (in my logs): `, referer: http://blablabal`
However, when i use: `print_r( $_REQUEST, true )`
I see all my html that has been sent. 
I've tried using the following to get the correct data out:
`$_POST , $_POST[''] , $_POST[0] , $_POST["data"] , $_POST['html_to_send']`
But I get nothing. Am I missing something, or do I need to somehow assign that variable in the javascript? If that's the case how would I do that?

Comment: What is the value of **html_to_send**?

Comment: @Berger it is `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the post variable you want to use in jquery like this:

```
var data = {
  somevar: 'my post value'
}
jQuery.post( "cmssave.php" , data, done_edit , "html" );
```

Further you might want to assing the success-function (done_edit) without parentheses, otherwise you would call the success function and assing it's return value.

And in PHP you get the value like this:

```
$data = $_POST['somevar'];
echo $data;
```

Comment: In your example i would actually have to do `somevar: html_to_send`. Is that valid? I tried it and i'm getting the exact same results. The html_to_send is actually `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML` if that matters

Comment: are you sure the request is ever sent? check for javascript errors in your js dev tools

Comment: So still not sure what happened, but apparently i get the data when i use `file_get_contents("php://input")` not sure what that's all about but using that bit of code works instead of the `$_POST['somevar'};`